# How to get list of all query params passed in url in RestTemplate springBoot application?

Tags: java, spring-boot, httprequest, resttemplate, query-string

Working on a springboot based rest service using RestTemplate. When query param is of limited number then it makes sense to define them as method parameters but I have a use case where a user can query for more than 1000 params. Obviously I cann't make 1000 params method so how do I get all the query params - something which achievable from HttpRequest object but isn't exposed here via springboot based controller method as far as I know. So what should be done in this case?

For example if there's just one query param say **query1** then below method will do desired work.
What if I have 1000+ such query params?

```
@RequestMapping(value = "urlPath", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<?> method1(**@RequestParam("query1") Optional<String> fieldsOptional**)
    {
//do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply add `@RequestParam Map<String, String> params` into your method